# Lookup data using ID

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I'm pretty sure this question is easy to solve but I can't figure it out and unfortunately haven't seen any questions on it either. Trimmed down, it comes to this:

The object Campaign has a custom field called Partner, a lookup field (Contact).

Basically, I would like to send an automatic email with info about a campaign, including details of the contact partner.

In the Email template, the field {!relatedto.Partner__c} returns the Contact-ID, which is good. But I can't figure out how to use this ID to show me the fields related to the contact, like Email and Telefon.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate 
     recipientType="Contact"
     relatedToType="Campaign"
     subject="Projekt Info: {!relatedTo.name}"
      <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
       <html>
       <body>
           Partner Contact details for Campaign {!relatedTo.name}
           Partner ID: {!relatedto.Partner__c}
           Name: ??
           Email: ??
           Tel: ??
       </body>
       </html>
      </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use '__r.' syntax. This way you can display parent object fields. Try:

```
{!relatedto.Partner__r.Name}
```